# Amavis not found by Postfix

Tags: postfix, amavis

I'm having this super annoying Postfix problem. I did a clean install of my web/mail/everything server and configured ISPConfig 3. Everything right now is working, except for Postfix. I can't send or receive any mail whatsoever. First, I fixed a MySQl permissions issue, now in the log I'm getting this amavis issue.

`Dec 18 09:44:19 example postfix/qmgr[30190]: warning: connect to transport private/amavis: No such file or directory`

I checked and amavis is running on both ports 10024 and 10026.

In Postfix's main.cf:

`content_filter = amavis:[127.0.0.1]:10024`

There is no mention of amavis in master.cf

I tried reinstalling the whole server, but that didn't help. I noticed when installing the ISPConfig tried to connect to amavis on ports 10025 and 10027, but main.cf has 10024, so ports can't be the issue, right?

I tried adding this line: `-o content_filter=amavis:[127.0.0.1]:10024` in `submission` and `smtps` sections of master.cf, as suggested by [this post](https://serverfault.com/questions/604571/what-is-stopping-postfix-from-delivering-mail-to-the-local-transport-agent), but that didn't work, so I removed these lines.

What could be the issue?

UPDATE: After adding lines specified by Craig, a new error comes up when sending a test email to my server:

```
Dec 18 10:26:58 example amavis[27362]: (27362-01) (!)connect to *:* failed, attempt #1: Can't connect to socket *:* using module IO::Socket::IP: Connection refused
Dec 18 10:26:58 example amavis[27362]: (27362-01) (!)RcRKEb15k-GM FWD from <------------@gmail.com> -> <admin@example.com>,  451 4.5.0 From MTA() during fwd-connect (All attempts (1) failed connecting to smtp:*:*): id=27362-01
Dec 18 10:26:58 example amavis[27362]: (27362-01) Blocked MTA-BLOCKED {TempFailedInbound}, [209.85.220.177]:33732 [209.85.220.177] <-----------@gmail.com> -> <admin@example.com>, Queue-ID: ----------------, Message-ID: -------------
```

Answer (score 2):

According to the [Postfix documentation](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#content_filter) for the `content_filter` parameter:

> After the message is queued, send the entire message to the specified
>   transport:destination. The transport name specifies the first field of
>   a mail delivery agent definition in master.cf; the syntax of the
>   next-hop destination is described in the manual page of the
>   corresponding delivery agent.

So, the `amavis` in your `content_filter` paramter needs to correspond to a transport name in `master.cf`.

For example:

```
amavis unix - - - - 2 smtp
        -o smtp_data_done_timeout=1200
        -o smtp_send_xforward_command=yes
```

To fix the error in your update, you may need to remove the square brackets:

```
content_filter = amavis:127.0.0.1:10024
```

Comment: Thanks, that's progress! I think Postfix found amavis, but now a new error comes up, adding it to original question

Comment: @ashraj98 see my updated answer

Comment: Darn, that didn't do it. I'm still getting the same error after updating `main.cf` and restarting postfix.